# Bitbucket hook api and third party credential saving

Tags: php, bitbucket, youtrack

I created integration between bitbucket and youtrack, when user committed codes to bickbucket it will automatically post to youtrack task notes but I'm having issue with youtrack credentials. So far I can only use the super user to post all notes, so is it possible to save third party credentials to bitbucket and include to the hook api?

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate on why this requires admin access to YouTrack?
Anyway, YouTrack 6.1 will have native integration with BitBucket via BB POST hook (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-16556).

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the reply. I want commit codes to be posted on youtrack. Anyway from docs of youtrack I came across with "runAs" https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD6/Apply+Command+to+an+Issue tried but did not worked. do you have any Idea? I already set user as updater.

Comment: It should be working. Please mind that (a) the user who calls the method should have the permission, not the one you pass as 'runAs' param, (b) this permission is per project, so make sure you have granted it in the correct project.